# Error on send an array to another function in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, yii

I get **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** message on click view button!?

I think problem is in this part: **onClick="showModal('+value+');"**

because of when i call the function out of [**onClick=""**], [**showModal(value);**] it's work!

what's wrong? any idea?

thanks.

**JQUERY :**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    divElement='';
    $.ajax({        
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('itemtype/index');?>",
       data:{},
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {

           $.each( data, function( i, value ) {
                    //showModal(value);
                    divElement+='<li class="itemtype-buttons">'+
                                '<a class="itemtype-button" href="#" onClick="showModal('+value+');" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="View"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>'+
                                '<a class="itemtype-button" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>'+
                                '<a class="itemtype-button" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>'+
                                '<a class="itemtype-button" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="List of '+value['name']+'"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>'+
                                '</li>';
                });

            divElement+='</div>';                           
            $('#itemtypes').html(divElement);   

       }
    });

}); 

//itemtype Controller
public function actionIndex()
{
        $data = Itemtype::model()->findAll();
        echo CJSON::encode($data);

}
 function showModal(arr){

            alert(arr['name']);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Read the property, `name` outside the string concatenation block and then use it,

```
var name = value['name'];
```

and inside the string,

```
'......title="List of '+ name +'">......'
```

Comment: Problem is in this part: **onClick="showModal('+value+');"** no **'......title="List of '+ name +'">......'**  i need work with the array in showModal(arr) function, alert(arr['name']); is just an example.